# How to get href tag in <a> in <span> with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, url, hyperlink, href

This is the case: I have multiple `<span>` tags with the class `.productLink`, with a link (`<a>`) containing a link to a page.

**Example**

```html
<span class="productLink">
    <a href="/Products/Category/item.html">A very nice product</a>
</span>
<span class="productLink">
    <a href="/Products/Category/otheritem.html">Also very nice product</a>
</span>
```

Now I would like to retrieve these links with jQuery.

I tried:

```
$('.productLink').each(function(index){
    console.log($(this + ' a').attr('href'));
});
```

But it threw:

> Uncaught Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object HTMLSpanElement]

**[See live fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h9a9qvdm/1/)**

What do I have to change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to select the anchor tag inside jquery selector like this:

```
$('.productLink > a').each(function(index){
    console.log($(this ).attr('href'));
});
```

Try it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/kvydgj6L/)

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is incorrect, `$(this + ' a')` in the statement `this` refers to DOM element, thus it gave the error.

As `anchor` is child of `productlink` you can use either of the method to traverse to `anchor` then can get its `href` attribute.

```
//Using context selector
console.log($('a', this).attr('href'));

//Using find method
console.log($(this).find('a').attr('href'));

//Using children method
console.log($(this).children('a').attr('href'));
```

Comment: Have I missed some thing?

Comment: Sometimes there are inappropriate down vote with out explanation it happened to me.

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log('start');
$('.productLink').each(function(index){
    var a = $(this).find('a')
    console.log(a.attr('href'));
});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/h9a9qvdm/2/)

You need to find the anchor tag inside the span so use `.find()` after getting the anchor tag get its href using `.attr()`